# how to prevent user from entering url and html tags in textarea

Tags: php, html

I am creating a feedback form and i dont want users to enter any url or any html tags in textarea field. I have tried many things but they dint work.

Comment: You don't want them to be able to enter the tags in the browser, or you just want to strip out the tags in a PHP script?

Comment: Instead of blocking input client side, clean it after it's entered, server side

Comment: Can we see what `many things` you've tried?

Comment: i want to strip tags.

Comment: i hv tried preg_match function, but i don't know, how to add multiple characters in the function for matching

Comment: You can limit what they can enter with JavaScript. Is that ok?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel if you are trying to do this front-end wise... Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651382/how-to-check-for-html-tags-and-then-add-error-in-jquery-validation

Answer (score 0):

i thing you have to trigger space character and check the word by the regular expression if it contains http or < then its tag or url you have to clear the textarea and give a pop you cannot enter the url or tags bit its partial workimg because hackers can break this by altering javascript so you have solution with server side also

Comment: You couldn't have posted this if SO had implemented what you suggested :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the JavaScript test method.

```
function Check(){

var reg =/<(.|\n)*?>/g; 

if (reg.test($('#TextAreaID').val()) == true) {

    var ErrorMsg ='not allowed';

    alert('ErrorMsg');

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if they have JavaScript disabled

Comment: Why? Why not just use server side validation with `ajax`?